# On secured site Images does not render into pdf - itext Flying Saucer html to pdf

Tags: flying-saucer

On secured site, If you have image src which starts with https://www.domain.com/appName/images/image.jpg
then it does not render the image into the PDF.

I am using itextrender class to render pdf from html code.

If the same image is used on unsecured site like http then it works properly.

I have implemented NaiveUserAgent class and overridden below methods
resolveAndOpenStream,getImageResource,resolveURI

Am I missing something? Or is there any way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a site that had invalid certificate. Make sure that the certificate is valid, or import it. See these for details:

- http://java.net/projects/xhtmlrenderer/lists/users/archive/2010-01/message/25
- http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=210